# Integrate $y=\int x^x(\ln x+1)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$y=\int x^x(\ln x+1)\ dx$$
I tried integration by parts but it became more complicated. So I did this:
$$dy=x^x(\ln x+1)$$
$$\frac1{x^x}dy=\ln x+1$$
$$\int\frac1{x^x}\ dy=\int(\ln x+1)\ dx=x\ln x=\ln x^x$$
Comparing with $\int\frac1y\ dy=\ln y$, I concluded $y=x^x+K$. Is there anything wrong with this method?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

Integration by parts is unnecessary, since the integral is amenable to a single, judiciously chosen substitution.  Note $$x^x = e^{x \log x}.$$  Then, what is the derivative of $x \log x$ with respect to $x$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the $\int\frac1{x^x}\ dy$ is wrong step because $x$ and $y$ are two **interdependent** variables ( None of them is constant with respect to each other ).

Now for answer of $y=\int x^x(\ln x+1)\ dx$,

consider 
$$
\frac{d(x^x)}{dx}=\frac{d(e^{xlnx})}{dx}=e^{xlnx}\frac{d(x\ln{x})}{dx}=e^{xlnx}(\ln{x}+1)=x^x(\ln{x}+1)
$$
So,
$$
y=\int x^x(\ln x+1)\ dx=\int \frac{d(x^x)}{dx} dx=x^x+K
$$

Comment: but when differentiating  f(x,y) we assume x as costant when diff, with respect of y and assume  y as a constant when diff, is in respect of x . I just folowed this rule and my result was correct,

Comment: @sirous First what are talking about is **Partial Differentiation** and what we are doing is **Total derivative**.Your answer is **luckly** correct or matching with the correct answer.....

Comment: you know that we can use total deravative to find y'=dy/dx  i.e.  y' = - (d(x,y)/dx)/d(x,y)/dy), and of course x and y are interrelated, we could not do that otherwise. my answer is not true by chance as you can see it is base on a logical comparison or better to say is based on constraction of a system of equations and solving it. Sometimes it is helpfull to use this methode to solve a problems.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x^x=y$ and find the $y'$. We have
$$y=x^x/\ln$$
$$\ln y=\ln x^x/'$$
$$\ln y=x\ln x$$
$$y'\cdot\frac{1}{y}=\ln x+1/\cdot y$$
$$y'=y(\ln x+1)$$
$$y'=x^x(\ln x+1)$$

For the given example, we have:

$$\int x^x(\ln x+1)dx=\int y' dy=\left(\int ydy\right)'=y=x^x+C$$